# How do I correctly work with ByteToMessageCodec.encode and direct buffers

Tags: netty, direct-buffer

I use a [ByteToMessageCodec](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageCodec.html) in my netty project. The encode has the following structure:

```java
protected abstract void encode(
    ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
    I msg,
    ByteBuf out
) throws Exception
```

In my case the `msg` is a message that holds a directBuffer that came from another channel and is to be forwarded.

My Questions:

- What is the best practice if `out.isWritable()` is false?
- Does `out.writeBytes(myMessage.directBuffer)` copy the memory if `out` is also a direct buffer?
- If it does copy the memory, can I just call `ctx.writeAndFlush(myMessage.directBuffer)` to prevent the memory copy?

There is a [source by norman maurer](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#32.0) telling something about this exact topic, but it seems to memory copy the buffers and doesn't answer all my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a ByteToMessageCodec at all and just use `MessageToMessageEncoder` in this case:

Then you could do:

```
protected abstract void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, I msg, List<Object> out) {
    out.add(msg.directBuffer);
}
```

This will prevent any memory copies.

Comment: will I also prevent memory copies if I use CompositeBuffers filled with direct buffers?